# Google Sheet Pivot Table with "standard" 0 value

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I am trying to create a Bottom 10 bar chart using a pivot table. The issue is that the pivot table has somehow a standard 0 value (there is no value for 0 in the data) which messes up the bar chart as that that[image] 0 is shown despite being irrelant. Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: add "Filter" where 2nd column is not 0

Comment: @player0 many thanks, how could I do that? I see only add Filter for the "order_profit" which has no value of 0 but no option to remove for the "sum of order_profit"?

Comment: Also if I add other pivot tables, I always have this "0" value showing up.

Comment: Found the solution, needed to filter for not empty as the pivot table is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to filter for "not empty", as the pivot table is dynamic there are empty rows for some values